# Custom UIGestureRecognizer for a two finger gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom UIGestureRecognizer for a two finger gesture that works perfectly except for it being very picky about how simultaneously the fingers have to touch the iOS-device for `touchesBegan` to be called with 2 touches. `touchesBegan` is often called with only one Touch even though I am trying to use two fingers.

Is there any way to make recognition for the number of Touches more forgiving in regards to how simultaneously you have to place your fingers on the touch screen?

I've noticed that a two finger tap is recognized even when you place first one finger and then another much later while still holding the first finger down.

Here is the code for my `touchesBegan` function:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {

      if touches.count != 2 {
         state = .failed
         return
      }

      // Capture the first touch and store some information about it.
      if trackedTouch == nil {
         trackedTouch = touches.min { $0.location(in: self.view?.window).x < $1.location(in: self.view?.window).x }
         strokePhase = .topSwipeStarted
         topSwipeStartPoint = (trackedTouch?.location(in: view?.window))!
         // Ignore the other touch that had a larger x-value
         for touch in touches {
            if touch != trackedTouch {
               ignore(touch, for: event)
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Your code says `if touches.count != 2 { state = .failed }`. That is the exact opposite of what you said you wanted. You said you _didn't_ want to fail immediately just because the count was not 2 yet. So don't do that!

Comment: But I only want to recognize a gesture with two fingers!? When do I know for sure that the gesture is not using two fingers and should fail? I have probably misunderstood something here...

Comment: You said: "Is there any way to make recognition for the number of Touches more forgiving in regards to how simultaneously you have to place your fingers on the touch screen?" And the answer is: Yes, don't fail instantly just because there are not two fingers. You are saying you want to be "more forgiving" but then you are being totally unforgiving!

Comment: Where should I check that the gesture is using two fingers? Won't touchesBegan be called only once? Or?

Comment: Can you post your gesture initialization code?

Comment: What about state `.possible` until `touches.count != 2`?

Comment: I've used various gesture recognisers and don't recall ever having this problem.  Without knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve, you may actually be better off using one of the subclasses UIPanGestureRecogniser or UISwipeGestureRecongiser which can specify min and max touches. These have always worked reliably for me

Comment: @Melodius the touchesBegan is called every-time a touch starts, so if you have only one finger on the screen, it is called, when the next finger is placed on the screen, it is called again, and so on...

Answer (score 2):

For two-finger gestures, `touchesBegan` is most likely going to be called twice: once you put the first finger on the screen, and once for the second one.

In the state you keep, you should keep track of both touches (or for that matter, all *current* touches), and only start the gesture once both touches have been received and the gesture's start condition has been met.

```
public class TwoFingerGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {
    private var trackedTouches: Set<UITouch> = []

    public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        for touch in touches {
            if self.trackedTouches.count < 2 {
                self.trackedTouches.insert(touch)
            }
            else {
                self.ignore(touch, for: event)
            }
        }

        if self.trackedTouches.count == 2 {
            // put your current logic here
        }
    }

    public override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    }

    public override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        self.trackedTouches.subtract(touches)
    }

    public override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        self.trackedTouches.subtract(touches)
    }

    public override func reset() {
        super.reset()

        self.trackedTouches = []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

don't worry about `touchesBegan:withEvent:` instead use `touchesEnded:withEvent:` or `touchesMoved:withEvent:` if the end state does not contain both fingers, set it as `.failed` otherwise set it as `.ended`

tapping the screen with more than one finger simultaneously is impossible, so during `touchesMoved:withEvent:` you will find two fingers. I'm not sure about `touchesEnded:withEvent:` this one probably won't work since removing two fingers simultaneously is just as hard as applying two fingers simultaneously, but it's worth a try to see how it reacts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend making your code a little more forgiving. Although touchesBegan/Moved/Ended/Cancelled respond to events of "one or more touches" (as stated in the Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder)) relying on the precision of a user to simultaneously touch the screen with 2 fingers is not ideal. This is assuming you have multi-touch enabled, which it sounds like you do.

Try tracking the touches yourself and executing your logic when you're collection of touches reaches 2. Obviously you'll also have to track when your touch amount becomes more or less and handle things accordingly, but I'd guess you're already handling this if you're gesture is meant to be for 2 fingers only (aside from the extra logic you'd have to add in touchesBegan).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the other guys answering with using touchesMoved:withEvent did not answer your question, but maybe you need a github example.

[Double touch move example.](https://github.com/popmedic/ios-doubletouch-example/tree/master/doubletouch)

Answer (score -1):

Is touchesMoved an option in order for you to achieve the desire outcome? Also you could implement a **counter** before setting the state to failed
Don't forget to set **isMultipleTouchEnabled = true**

```
  override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if touches.count != 2 {
        print("we do NOT have two touches")
        if counter > 100   { // 100 "more fogiven"
            state = .failed
        }
        counter += 1
        return
    } else {
        print("we have to two touches")
    }
```